# How to find out whether a specific picklist value was selected today?

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, custom-field

I need to create a new custom object only when both of the following happen in the same day:

- Contact.Custom_field__c = 'myValue' (so this picklist value has been selected today)
- A Task of type Call and status Complete has been created on the same contact record and in the same day

My approach to this has been the following,

I would like to be able to find out whether a specific picklist value on the Contact object has been selected today? I need to do this in Apex and not the UI. For example: In my Task trigger after insert, I check the value for the Contact.custome_filed__c and it matches what I'm looking for 'myValue'. now I'd like to know if this picklist value has been changed from something other than 'myValue' to 'myValue' **TODAY**? *(note, it's not a multi-select picklist)*

I was thinking of using a hidden checkbox with a combination of a trigger on the contact object and check the box once 'myValue' gets selected, and uncheck otherwise, and also to keep this box checked just until the next day, I was thinking of creating some sort of automated process either a process builder, flow, or even a batch apex. So with this, I can check the checkbox value in my Task trigger.

**Please help me find out the best way and best practices to do this. Thanks!**

Comment: This feels like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Can you describe the purpose of this picklist value and the automation you are trying to achieve? There is probably a better solution then the one you are attempting.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/308251/edit) your question instead of adding the information into the comments

Comment: Contact field history can help with the tracking